# i cound not find the solution of inline style condition

Tags: node.js, ejs

Please help me, I could not find the solution of inline style and if this is not possible then tell me the alternative to render dynamic property change in style. The snippet is find from below like, and you can see what is error:
[error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSrPQ.png)

I tried lots but could not fix it.

This is my code:

```
<div 
  class="template"
  style="border-color: <%= details && details.brandAndLogoData && details.brandAndLogoData.brand_color ? details.brandAndLogoData.brand_color : '#000000' %>"
>
  <% if (details.brandAndLogoData && details.brandAndLogoData.brand_logo &&
  details.brandAndLogoData.brand_logo.url) { %>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td
              align="<%= details.brandAndLogoData.logo_alignment %>"
              valign="top"
              style="background-color: #ffffff"
            >
              <img
                src="<%= details.brandAndLogoData.brand_logo.url %>"
                alt="brandLogoBtn"
                style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <% } %>
  <div style="padding: 0 20px">
    <p><%= details.text %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```